# How to repair grub to work with multiple hard drives?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-8, bootloader, os-prober

On my computer I have multiple hard drives. One of them has Ubuntu 14.10 and the other has Windows 8.1. I messed up my boot loader and know only Ubuntu appears in the grub list. Windows 8.1 is on the first hard-drive, and Ubuntu is on the second. How do I repair grub to see Windows 8.1? Also, my computer was UEFI before and I changed that. Could that be a problem?

Comment: Windows 8 that came preintstalled with the computer will only boot in the UEFI mode, and won't boot in the Legacy mode.

Comment: And then if Windows is UEFI, you have to install Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode on second drive. Otherwise the only way you can boot is from UEFI menu and even then you may have to turn on/off UEFI or BIOS settings. Best to see details of what you have done: Post link to Summary report: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair  Do not run any Autofix. That just installs grub to all drives.